# WPF - Drop Data Table On Data Grid

Tags: wpf

I Want to implement Drop Operation On Data Grid So I drop a data Table on Data Grid.
But When I drop another Table on it Previously Dropped Table Gets Overwrite . How to Preserve Both Tables On Data Grid at One Time.

Comment: Do the Tables have the same columns ? Or are these completely different Tables ?

Comment: Totlay Different Tables

Comment: Then there is no chance. Since you seem to have "AutoGenerateColumns" set to true this will always override the existing structure of the grid when dropping another...

Comment: Since you only have 1 header you cannot have more tables in one grid how about adding a new datagrid under the other when dropping ?!

Comment: i know this but may be another way to do this

Comment: Because i want to show Firstly All Column of First Table than Second Table Columns Then third  So On....  Or there is another tool to Do operations Like that

Comment: Never heard of one... I can think of a Treeview where you can select the datatables and it then displays the selected DataGrid .. I dont think it is possible to show all on one datagrid

Comment: you can do that robin but more than drop it needs to about handling dynamic columns